# Proper use of Modulus "%" operator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, mathematics

## Objective:

Gather pour points to define a specific-sized watershed. In this case, 1000 pixels. (for this thought exercise, watershed is to mean any point that flows through a pour point, regardless of size, not the NHD definition)

## Layers:

DEM, flow direction, flow accumulation, the like.

Flow accumulation symbolized with 1/2 standard deviations on top of the DEM:[image: flow accumulation map]
My mathematician brother suggested the use of the modulus operator, which returns the remainder of a division problem, thus allowing something like `Con(("flow_accum" % 1000) < 10, 1, 0) in the Raster Calculator.
Theoretically, this should return a blip in the stream every thousand pixels of flow accumulation, but it doesn't.
What just the modulus ( just "flow_accum" % 1000) returns is this:
[image: modulus map]
I do not know how to interpret this. It should have low values for all pixels that are not near a X,000 but it appears to have just done some sort of rescaling to 1000 or something.
I did a manual selection of the first 12 watersheds with:

```
Con(("flow_accum" == 1000), 1, Con(("flow_accum" == 2000),2, Con(("flow_accum" == 3000)
,3,Con(("flow_accum" == 4000),4,Con(("flow_accum" == 5000),5,Con(("flow_accum" == 6000)
,6,Con(("flow_accum" == 7000),7,Con(("flow_accum" == 8000),8,Con(("flow_accum" == 9000)
,9,Con(("flow_accum" == 10000),10,Con(("flow_accum" == 11000),11,Con(("flow_accum" == 12000)
,12,Con(("flow_accum" == 13000),13,Con(("flow_accum" == 14000),14,0))))))))))))))
```

Which after running the watershed tool, returned this:
[image: manual watershed delineation]

## What I need help with is making sense of the output of the modulus function, and defining arbitrarily-sized watersheds.

Comment: Does the range of values in your modulus raster actually go from 0 to 999? It looks like your con statement should only create values of 0 or 1 or NO_DATA.

Comment: No it doesn't, the con statement does return a binary mask, but didn't look useful, so I tried just the mod statement, which is what I pictured. I edited it to clarify, thanks.

Comment: 0-999 is a correct range of values for x % 1000.
1000 % 1000 = 0, 
1001 % 1000 = 1, 
1999 % 1000 = 999,
It seems to me like what you want is Con(("flow_accum" % 1000) == 0, 1, 0).

Comment: That gets me much closer. It still flags the 0 flow accumulation pixels as 1, which is to be expected, so now I need to just remove the 0 pixels first.

Comment: Con(("flow_accum" < 2),0,Con(("flow_accum" % 1000) ==0,1,0))
gives the expected result, but now I'm wondering if that's what I really wanted, since there are a lot of streams that never hit an exact thousand in flow accumulation.

Comment: So 0 % 1000 = 0? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: **Please complete the question:** exactly *how* do you want to choose those 1000 pour points? At equal distances along the streams? At equal intervals of flow accumulation? In a grid covering the watershed? Something else?

Comment: I don't want 1000 pour points, I want pour points that define 1000-pixel watersheds, however many that might be.

Comment: That would be every point whose flow accumulation equals 1000. Because many points will not have *exactly* 1000 for their flow accumulation, you might want to select those whose flow accumulation equals or exceeds 1000 and there is at least one point within its one-pixel neighborhood with a flow accumulation strictly less than 1000.  There can be a large number of such points and their watersheds will overlap (considerably). I am mystified about the intended use of the modulus function, so I suspect you would really like to ask a different question than the one you seem to be asking... .